# Rails 4 will_paginate repeated results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

One of my index pages shows the same resource on multiple pages with `will_paginate`. I have other pages that are paginating perfectly and can't figure out what's wrong.

In my model I have this method:

```
self.per_page = 10

def self.index_search(query)
  if query.present?
    self.approved.where("name ilike :q or ko_name ilike :q", q: "%#{query}%")
      .order(date: :asc).group("id")
  else
    approved.upcoming.order(date: :asc).group("id")
  end
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
def index
  @events = Event.index_search(params[:query]).paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

And in the view:

```
<%= will_paginate @events, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

Typically, the last item on the first page is repeated in the same spot on the second page.

I added the `.group("id")` to the method after digging around on StackOverflow, but I'm stumped at what I should be looking at next.

edit:

It appears if I change `self.per_page = 10` to a number greater than 12, the repeat issue goes away. I would really like to keep it at 10 per page.

Edit: it may also be relevant that all of the events have a `date` field and the paginated events all have the same date value.

Comment: What the query rails is executing?

Comment: ```SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."approved" = 't' AND (date > '2014-05-31') GROUP BY id ORDER BY "events"."date" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0```

Comment: are you sure, the duplicates are really "duplicates"? Meaning, do the duplicates have unique id's?

Comment: yes, here's a sample of the sql output from the pagination query on the first two pages, these are IDs. Notice the last one is the same in both arrays: ```106, 120, 90, 134, 126, 135, 117, 98, 133, 129```
and ```132, 100, 112, 103, 131, 115, 86, 96, 110, 129```

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully not digging up old memories, but..

I also have come across this issue. For me it was caused by using PostgreSQL - my solution was to add an additional sort_by clause for id.

Changing

`events.order(:start_date, :series_id).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)`

to

`events.order(:start_date, :series_id, :id).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)`

And everything was right in the world, again.

Issue raised and answered on will_paginate: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/420

Comment: Thank you, after many hours of searching I found this...